# Картинка злезает на футер при скролле

Tags: html, css, scss

Всем привет!

При скролле страницы вниз картинка залезает на футер. Как это исправить и ограничить скролл картинки границами дива? (если я думаю в правильном направлении). Линк на страницу:
http://tek.lv/index.php/ru/raschitat-smetu

Картинка имеет наложенные слои (11шт) через свойство z-index, все слои с бэкграундом находятся в отдельном диве. В зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов накладываются те или иные слои на картинку.

```
css для дива со слоями и фоновой картинкой:

.image-right {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;    
}

для картинок:

.my-image {
    width: 30%;
    justify-items: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;    
}

для слоев:

.img_layer_smeta {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `position: fixed;` фиксирует элемент на экране пользователя, из-за этого и все проблемы. Уберите его.

Comment: Спасибо, убрал. После этого все отдельные слои расположились хаотично на странице. Если есть возможность посмотрите по ссылке, что получилось. Надо, чтобы картинка двигалась при скролле , но не заходила на футер.

Comment: На самом деле они расположились не хаотично, а друг за другом. Вы можете использовать свойство position: absolute, после чего подогнать картинку в нужные вам координаты, но это решение явно не гибкое, то есть при изменении размера экрана - вы столкнетесь с еще бОльшим количеством проблем.

Comment: Попробовал position:absolute; В этом случае картинка не движется вместе со скроллом :) Спасибо за комментарии!

Comment: @Новичок, если хотите, чтобы картинка двигалась за скроллом страницы, но не лезла на футер, можете использовать еще один костыль. Оставляете position: fixed и указываете margin-bottom: 300px или сколько вам там нужно, по высоте футера, тогда она на него залезать не будет, но опять же - это дикий костыль.

Comment: Попробовал, что-то ничего не изменилось. Видимо у меня там наколбашено уже сильно, без бутылки не разобраться :)) margin:bottom надо применять к .img_layer_smeta ?

Comment: Сам только что понял, что неправильно посоветовал вам про margin-bottom. Так что этот костыль даже не используйте)

Comment: Да, уже убрал. В интернетах нашел свойство position:sticky;  якобы это свойство ограничивает движение картинки рамками дива, но так же не помогло)